# How to prove following limit doesn't exists?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the following limit if it exists.
I don't know how to prove a limit doesn't exists for these type of questions.
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}  \frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3-x}$

Comment: Hint: If you approach along $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ the limit is $1$.

Comment: Where is your own work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along $x=0$ this is 0.

Along $x=y^3$ this is 1.